# КГБшник или кагэбэшник / МВДшник или эмвэдэшник

Tags: грамотная-речь, сокращения, аббревиатуры

Как всё-таки правильно пишутся в тексте слова от буквенных аббревиатур? Много видел статей, а также книг и всяких постов с МВДшниками, КГБшниками, ПТУшниками. Однако Грамота предлагает писать эмвэдэшник, кагэбэшник, пэтэушник.

Он является бывшим МВДшником/КГБшником/ПТУшником.

Он является бывшим эмвэдэшником/кагэбэшником/пэтэушником.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Почему Грамота предлагает так писать? Потому что эти и другие подобные слова зафиксированы в орфографических словарях ([**эмвэдэшник**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&word=%D0%AD%D0%BC%D0%B2%D1%8D%D0%B4%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA), [**кагэбэшник**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%8D%D0%B1%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&all=x), [**пэтэушник**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%8D%D1%82%D1%8D%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)). Такие слова труднее воспринимаются на письме, чем *МВДшник, КГБшник, ПТУшник*, но существует правило, которое "в идеале" нужно соблюдать.

[**Аббревиатуры и производные от них слова**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=95) (справочник Лопатина):

> **§ 204.**
> <...>
> В формах склонения буквенных аббревиатур и в словах, образованных от буквенных аббревиатур с помощью суффиксов, используется только второй способ передачи аббревиатурной основы — по названиям букв, напр.: *бэтээры* (от *БТР*), *кагэбэшник* (от *КГБ*), *гэбист* (от *ГБ*), *кавээнщик* (от *КВН*), *цековский* (от *ЦК*), *цеэсковский* (от *ЦСКА*), *эсэнгэвский* (от *СНГ*), *кабэшный* (от *КБ*), *гэпэушный* (от *ГПУ*).

В Нацкорпусе русского языка есть **всего пять текстов** с *КГБшниками*, три из которых принадлежат одному автору:
*А вообще-то в этом нет ничего удивительного: комсомольцы и **КГБшники** первыми почувствовали прелесть личной свободы* (Евгений Попов. Подлинная история «Зеленых музыкантов». 1997).

А вот написание по правилам встречается в **82 текстах**, например:
*Но поскольку время шло, моя публикация настоящего внимания не привлекла, **кагэбэшники** успокоились и подобрели* (Владимир Войнович. Дело № 34840. 1999).
*Хозяин не был похож на секретного **кагэбэшника*** (Андрей Макаревич. Дом. 2001).
*Она вывела меня на улицу, бесстрашно подарив **кагэбэшнику** в будке улыбку и цветок* (Николай Климонтович. Дорога в Рим. 1991-1994).

Answer (score 0):

Можно и КГБшник написать по-русски, просто там черточка нужна КГБ-шник.
По правилам русского языка при наращении аббревиатуры всегда нужна черточка (по-научному - дефис).

Comment: Про БТР вообще смешно. Уже давно устоялось на БТР-е, спрыгнуть с БТР-а. Вы в каком лесу, блин, живете?

Comment: Элси, не могли бы Вы привести правила о наращении аббревиатур?

Comment: Правила это не ко мне.