# СССРский/эсэсэсэрский

Tags: орфография, прилагательные, сокращения, аббревиатуры

Как сделать прилагательное от *СССР*?

1. СССРский.
2. Эсэсэсэрский.

Comment: Верно: _советский_.

Comment: Фу! Бяка! Скучно!

Comment: Вашего слова нет в словарях.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть правило ([**справочник Лопатина**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=95#), § 204):

> В формах склонения буквенных аббревиатур и в словах, образованных от буквенных аббревиатур с помощью суффиксов, используется только второй способ передачи аббревиатурной основы — по названиям букв, напр.: <...> ***эсэнгэвский*** (от *СНГ*).

Из [**Нацкорпуса**](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkgqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCJQojCiEKA3JlcRIaChjQrdGB0Y3RgdGN0YHRjdGA0YHQutC40YUwAQ==):
*Так как я находился в самой «страшной» из всех **эсэсэсэрских** тюрем, во «внутреннем лубянском изоляторе», то и обыск был соответственный*.

В орфографическом словаре ([**Грамота.ру**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%8D%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) зафиксировано с другим суффиксом:
**эсэсэсэровский** (от СССР).

С сайта [**Картаслов.ру**](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC/%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%8D%D1%81%D1%8D%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9):
*Устремлённость к социалистическому миродержавию, сохранявшаяся и в условиях победы социализма в одной стране, сформировала своеобразный **эсэсэсэровский** и отнюдь не русский, как порой утверждается, наступательный национализм*.

Похожий вопрос: [**КГБшник или кагэбэшник / МВДшник или эмвэдэшник**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476010/%D0%9A%D0%93%D0%91%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%8D%D0%B1%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%9C%D0%92%D0%94%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B2%D1%8D%D0%B4%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA).

Answer (score 1):

С момента образования СССР появилась необходимость в таком или ему подобном прилагательном, поэтому все давно уже сделано (отыменное прилагательное от СССР образовано)...
Вот вариант от Маяковского:
Речка,
/где и уткам
/было узко,
где и по колено
/не было ногам бы,
шла
/плотвою флотов
/речка Т_у_скарь:
курс на Курск -
/и эСэСэСэРский Гамбург.
Всякого Нью-Йорка ньюйоркистей,
раздинамливая
/электрический раскат,
маяки
/просверливающей зоркости
в девяти морях
/слепят
/глаза эскадр.

На прошлом, тринадцатом по счету фестивале в Пхеньяне казалось, что дорогостоящие праздники юной соцноменклатуры и прогрессивных борцов за свободу за эсэсэсэровский счет, закончились навсегда. [Рустам Арифджанов. Фестиваль (1997) // «Столица», 12.08.1997]

Надо отметить, что эти варианты прилагательного имеют крайне узкое применение. Прижилось и широко используется  прилагательное «советский».

Варианты переноса слова: эсэ-сэ-сэ-ров-ский